# Simplify a fraction of vectors and matrices of form $\frac{b^2}{a\cdot c}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, vectors, covariance

How to simplify or reduce
$$\left(\frac{\left(\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol\mu \right)^2}{\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{1} \cdot \boldsymbol\mu ^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol\mu  }\right)$$

whose terms can be grouped as $\frac{b^2}{a\cdot c}$ if it helps any. Here are the dimensions of the vectors and matrices for some integer $N$:

- $\mathbf{1}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}$ is a vector of ones
- $\boldsymbol\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}$ is a vector of real values
- $\mathbf{\Sigma}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is the covariance matrix

I'm also interested in the steps towards reduction.

Comment: It's less than one by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Without further assumptions, it cannot be simplyifed, I guess.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: What are you not understanding about my statement?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. would a Gaussian assumption lead to simplification

Comment: If we assume that $\Sigma$ is non-degenerate, then $\Sigma$ is as inverse of a covariance matrix symmetric and positive definite. Then, by Cauchy-Schwartz $(x\cdot \Sigma^{-1}y)^{2}\le x\cdot\Sigma^{-1}x y\cdot\Sigma^{-1}y$.